# How to make sequence first garb web data and second execute function in swift

Tags: ios, swift, sequence

I have a function to download web content. When I call it and call another function after, XCode execute second one first. Even though I put web function in this method

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()){
      getWeather() 
}
println(notValed)
```

Comment: It's because you're doing "async" calls (which is clearly seen in "dispatch_ASYNC"()).

Comment: so to solve the problem what should i do?

Comment: You should search SO for it has many similar questions and answers about this.